# WebAPI adding class titles at beginning

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, rest, json.net

I serialized a REST API response to JSON through ASP.NET Web API. 
Here is my result: [JSON Format](https://api.myjson.com/bins/de68q).

I'm accessing this result via the following link: `http://192.168.2.35:55281/api/Students`. So I want to make my JSON format start with a class title, for example:

```
"Students": [
  {
    "Id": 18,
    "Type": "Sayısal",
    "Class_Id": 9
  }
]
```

But unfortunately as you can see from the link at the top, I haven't got a title for `Students`. How I can activate it on my Web API?

**Here My Controller:**

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController
{
    private DBClassroomEntities db = new DBClassroomEntities();

    // GET: api/Students
    public IQueryable<Student> GetStudent()
    {
        return db.Student;
    }

    // GET: api/Students/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
    {
        Student student = db.Student.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);

        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(student);
    }

    // PUT: api/Students/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutStudent(int id, Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != student.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!StudentExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Students
    [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Student.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = student.Id }, student);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Students/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
        Student student = db.Student.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Student.Remove(student);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(student);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool StudentExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Student.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is change the response type you are returning in your api/Students method, create the Model type to match what you requested and return that model ( if needed look into AutoMapper on how to facilitate this process )

Comment: There does not have to be a class title of students, this makes it more difficult to deserialize.Your current json format is fine as is. is there a specific reason you would prefer this?

Comment: @arlanschouwstra yes i want to do that for parsing my model easier at Android.

Comment: @HalilŞahin how would this make parsing *easier*? Unless you return *different* payloads from the same URL and depend on some attribute in the response to decide how to treat the string. BTW what you posted in the question isn't JSON. You can't have a top-level attribute like that. A JSON string must have a single root item, either an object or an array

Comment: @HalilŞahin if you want to return the results in a `Students` attribute you can write `return OK(new {Students=someListOfStudents});`. This will return a valid JSON string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he already has a valid format shown in his link. He wants to add a class string in front of it, which can be a accepted json format. You could do so as `return OK(new Dictionary<string, Students> ("Students", Students))`

Comment: @arlanschouwstra that's not JSON. You can't have a naked attribute. JSON contains *Javascript*. Javascript objects are dictionaries, defined using curly braces. No curly braces, no dictionary

Comment: @arlanschouwstra i tried still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new class `StudentList`:

   ```
   public class StudentList
   {
       public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change this method:

   ```
   // GET: api/Students
   public IQueryable<Student> GetStudent()
   {
       return db.Student;
   }
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   // GET: api/Students
   [ResponseType(typeof(StudentList))]
   public IHttpActionResult GetStudents()
   {
       StudentList studentList = new StudentList() 
       {
           Students = db.Student.ToList();
       }

       return Ok(studentList);
   }
   ```

The JSON returned from this method will look similar to this:

```
{
  "Students": [
    {
        "Id": 18,
        "Type": "Sayısal",
        "Class_Id": 9,
        "Group_Id": 1,
        "FName": "Hüseyin",
        "LName": "Biçen"
    },
    {
        "Id": 20,
        "Type": "Yabancı Dil",
        "Class_Id": 7,
        "Group_Id": 6,
        "FName": "Hasan",
        "LName": "Naser"
    }
  ]
}
```